# Find $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})$.

I [found](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080323085754AAzUW3b) an answer on Yahoo, which I don't completely understand.

> > Recall that an isomorphism of a cyclic group must carry generator to generator. The only generators of $\mathbb{Z}$ are $1$ and $-1$.
> >
> > Hence the only automorphisms possible are: $f(n)=n$ and $f(n)=-n$.
> >
> > Therefore $|\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})|=2$ and must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Could someone try to explain this to me, maybe formulated a bit otherwise? Especially the first line 'Recall that .. to generator'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb Z$, then $f(n) = nf(1)$, so $f$ is completely determined by where it sends $1$ (a generator of $\mathbb Z$). Now, if $f(1) = m$, then $f(n) = nf(1) = nm$, so the image of $f$ is the subgroup $m\mathbb Z$. Thus, if we want $f$ to be surjective, then necessarily $f(1) \in \{-1,1\}$.